# Cast of parameterized delegate to non-parameterized analogue

Tags: c#, delegates

Can anyone suggest why I cannot cast non-generic delegate to generic with appropriate type parameters?
Particularly having two delegates as shown below

1. `public delegate void NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)`
2. `public delegate void WeakEventHandler<TSource, TEvent>(TSource sender, TEvent e)`

and a delegate variable

3. `NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler;`

I can't cast handler to `WeakEventHandler<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>`. Does anyone know what's the reason for this?

Comment: Sorry, lost angle brackets. I meant the following cast:
(WeakEventHandler<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>)handler;

Comment: It would have been easier to help you if you'd provided a [mcve] rather than a list of bits of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, they're different types. Imagine you had two classes like this:

```
public class A1
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class A2
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

They're different classes despite *looking* equivalent - and you couldn't cast between `A1` and `A2`. It's the same with delegates.

What you *can* do is wrap the existing delegate:

```
var weakHandler = new WeakEventHandler<object, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(handler);
```

That creates a new delegate that invokes the original delegate when the new delegate is invoked.

Comment: Well, agree, from that point they are different...
Was confused a bit because lambda expression "casts" just fine:

'
    public class Main {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            GenericHandler<object, int> gHandler = null;
            NonGenericHandler ngHandler = null;
            gHandler = ngHandler; //<<Cant convert type...
            gHandler = (object o, int i) => { }; //<<works just fine.
        }
    }
'
Anyway, thank you for the solution.

Comment: @AlexIgna: A lambda expression doesn't have a type in itself; the compiler checks that the lambda expression can be used for the delegate type, and constructs a delegate of the appropriate type. It's not converting from one type to another.